# use of Cordova's secure storage plugin produces "Unknown provider" error, why?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to user Secure storage (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/secure-storage/) on Ionic application.

In my controller:

```
    .controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope, SecureStorage) {
        var ss = new SecureStorage(
                function () {
                    console.log('Success')
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log('Error ' + error);
                },
                'my_app');
                var key = 'aaa';
```

ERROR:

> ionic.bundle.js:26799 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   SecureStorageProvider <- SecureStorage <- ExampleCtrl

But it don't know the SecureStorage provider.

Do you know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I added the error, it simply don't know the provider

Comment: The link you referred to is an angular2 plugin, but it seems your code is using angular1

Comment: Have you included the module in app.js? Also looks like you are using angular2 plugin in angular1 project.

Comment: Check docs. if `SecureStorageProvider` is available for Angular V1.

Comment: You are using ionic2 SecureStorage Plugin in ionic 1 code.It will not work. Refer @JanP answer below.Its a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
.controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var ss = new cordova.plugins.SecureStorage(
            function () {
                console.log('Success');
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log('Error ' + error);
            },
            'my_app');
});
```

So, remove SecureStorage from the controller arguments and add `cordova.plugins.` on the second line.

And don't forget to install the plugin (of course):

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-secure-storage --save
```

Now you can use the functions on `ss`, but don't use the documentation in the link you provided, since this is Ionic 2 documentation. Use the plugin documentation in stead: https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap the SecureStorage in a service then use the service in the controller.

```
import { SecureStorage } from 'ionic-native';
.factory('secureFactory',function(){

     this.createStorage = function(){
       var ss = new SecureStorage(
            function () {
                console.log('Success')
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log('Error ' + error);
            },
            'my_app');
        return ss;
     }

 })
```

in the controller

```
 .controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope, secureFactory) {
    var sss = secureFactory.createStorage();
 })
```